# How to draw multiple GeoDataFrames (overlapping) in one map figure?

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm trying to draw a few different layers onto a single map in GeoPandas, but only the last one is ever displayed.

Now, my eventual goal is draw some raster-like polygon 'pixels' based on another numeric column, and I want that overlaid over a map of my area of interest.

Here's what an example with some large, manually created squares:

```
# modules you'd need to run this
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import polygon
%matplotlib inline

# a few example squares
square1 = {
    'geometry':polygon.Polygon([
        (-4164911.2311, 2834480.454299999),
        (-3514002.14019091, 2834480.454299999),
        (-3514002.14019091, 3394480.454299999),
        (-4164911.2311, 3394480.454299999),
        (-4164911.2311, 2834480.454299999)
    ]),
    'count':95
}
square2 = {
    'geometry':polygon.Polygon([
        (-4164911.2311, 3394480.454299999), 
        (-3514002.14019091, 3394480.454299999), 
        (-3514002.14019091, 3954480.454299999), 
        (-4164911.2311, 3954480.454299999), 
        (-4164911.2311, 3394480.454299999)
    ]),
    'count':65
}
square3 = {
    'geometry': polygon.Polygon([
        (-4164911.2311, 3954480.454299999),
        (-3514002.14019091, 3954480.454299999),
        (-3514002.14019091, 4514480.454299999),
        (-4164911.2311, 4514480.454299999),
        (-4164911.2311, 3954480.454299999)
    ]),
    'count':0
}

# squares put into a GeoDataFrame
squares = gpd.GeoDataFrame([square1,square2,square3],
crs={"proj-string: +proj=aea"})

# world country outlines, included with GeoPandas library
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
# selecting only for the western hemisphere
westhem = world[(world['continent'] == 'North America') | 
                (world['continent'] == 'South America')]

# ensuring crs info aligns; squares relate to data written onto 
# Albers Equal Area projection
westhem.crs = {"proj-string: +proj=aea"}

# somewhere I read that establishing your pyplot objects is always a 
# good idea
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,sharex=True,sharey=True,figsize=(11,11))

# this should draw some black outlines for countries
westhem.plot(ax=ax,color='white', edgecolor='black');
# and this should map my squares onto the SAME axis.
squares.plot(ax=ax,cmap='Reds',column='count',legend=True);
```

Instead of drawing both maps, however, I just get this:

[image: map of squares with no countries]

How do I make sure both maps appear together so that my squares have context?

Comment: You are mixing projections. That tiny dot around 0, 0 coordinates is your world map which is in degrees, while your squares are in some projected crs.

Comment: well, I thought defining the crs attributes was supposed to match them up. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You did not define cars correctly, check Geopandas docs for that. You need `westhem = westhem.to_crs{"proj-string: +proj=aea"}` instead. I am unable to try it at the moment, but that should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You need appropriate CRS conversion to bring two data sources into a common reference system. In the code below, the `naturalearth_lowres` basemap data is converted to `AlbersEqualArea` for plotting. Some parameters of `AlbersEqualArea` I use might be wrong, but they can be corrected and rerun to get the output you need.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import polygon
from cartopy import crs as ccrs

# proj4str  = ccrs.AlbersEqualArea().proj4_init
# '+ellps=WGS84 +proj=aea +lon_0=0.0 +lat_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +lat_1=20.0 +lat_2=50.0 +no_defs'

# a few example squares
square1 = {
    'geometry':polygon.Polygon([
        (-4164911.2311, 2834480.454299999),
        (-3514002.14019091, 2834480.454299999),
        (-3514002.14019091, 3394480.454299999),
        (-4164911.2311, 3394480.454299999),
        (-4164911.2311, 2834480.454299999)
    ]),
    'count':95
}
square2 = {
    'geometry':polygon.Polygon([
        (-4164911.2311, 3394480.454299999), 
        (-3514002.14019091, 3394480.454299999), 
        (-3514002.14019091, 3954480.454299999), 
        (-4164911.2311, 3954480.454299999), 
        (-4164911.2311, 3394480.454299999)
    ]),
    'count':65
}
square3 = {
    'geometry': polygon.Polygon([
        (-4164911.2311, 3954480.454299999),
        (-3514002.14019091, 3954480.454299999),
        (-3514002.14019091, 4514480.454299999),
        (-4164911.2311, 4514480.454299999),
        (-4164911.2311, 3954480.454299999)
    ]),
    'count':0
}

# squares put into a GeoDataFrame
squares = gpd.GeoDataFrame([square1,square2,square3],
                           crs={"proj-string: +proj=aea"})

# world country outlines, included with GeoPandas library
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
# selecting only for the western hemisphere
westhem = world[(world['continent'] == 'North America') | 
                (world['continent'] == 'South America')]

# prep AlbersEqualArea projection
# default parameters:
#  central_longitude=0.0  <-- not good for USA
#  standard_parallels=(20.0, 50.0)

# for demo purposes: parameters used here may not match the ..
#  intended CRS you want
crs_aea = ccrs.AlbersEqualArea(central_longitude=0, \
                               standard_parallels=(20, 50))

# crs_aea = ...
# '+ellps=WGS84 +proj=aea +lon_0=-75 +lat_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +lat_1=20 +lat_2=50 +no_defs'

# convert the geo dataframe to the projection (crs_aea) just created
westhem_crs_aea = westhem.to_crs(crs_aea.proj4_init)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,sharex=True,sharey=True,figsize=(11,11))

# this should draw some black outlines for countries
westhem_crs_aea.plot(ax=ax, color='lightgray', edgecolor='black');

# and this should map my squares onto the SAME axis
squares.plot(ax=ax,cmap='Reds',column='count',legend=True);
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

Hope this is useful.